# How do I filter an OData set based on the length/count of a collection property

Tags: odata

Imagine this set of `People` where each person has a `Trips` property which is an array of `Trip`.

For example: https://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Trips

I want to keep only the people who have exactly 3 trips.

I would try this filter: `$filter=Trips/$count eq 3`

```
https://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=Trips/$count eq 2&$expand=Trips
```

But it does not work, I get this error:

> The parent value for a property access of a property '$count' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.

According to this reference, it should work:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752351

> Example 28: entity count in a $filter expression. Note that the spaces around gt are for readability of the example only; in real URLs they must be percent-encoded as %20.
>
> http://host/service/Categories?$filter=Products/$count gt 0

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess it's an error from the OData Server.